# Is this an overflow or something?

Tags: flash, if-statement, overflow

Well hello everyone, im new at Flash Builder, and programming in general. some help please i can't see my mistake.
This is the error that appears: 
An ActionScript error has occurred:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
at Main/button1_clickHandler()[C:\Users\DiegoIván\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\Energía\src\Main.mxml:39]
at Main/__calcular_click()[C:\Users\DiegoIván\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\Energía\src\Main.mxml:93]
```

And here is the whole code

```
            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            focos=int(A.text);
            watts=int(B.text);
            dias=int(resd.text);
            wattsCons=(watts*focos)/1000+wattsAnt;
            lbsCons=(watts*focos*1.85)/1000+lbsAnt;
            precio=((watts*.957)*100)/100;
            res.text= String((dias*int((wattsCons)*100)/100))+ ' KW  ';
            res3.text= String((dias*int((lbsCons*0.45359237)*100)/100)) +' Kg';
            res5.text= String((dias*int((precio)*100)/100)) + 'MXN';
            if (int(A.text) == 75 )
            {
                (ahorra2.text= String(0.45359237*int((focos*20*1.85)/1000)*100/100)+ ' Kg ') 
                (ahorra1.text= String(int(focos*20)/1000)+ ' KW ')
                (ahorra3.text= String(int(.957*20)*100/100)+ ' MXN ')
            }else (int(A.text) == 25 )
            {
                (ahorra2.text= String(int((focos*6*1.85)/1000)*100/100)+ ' Kg ') 
                (ahorra1.text= String(int(focos*6)/1000)+ ' KW ')
                (ahorra3.text= String(int(.957*6)*100/100)+ ' MXN ')
            }
            }
```

AND...

```
    <s:Button id="calcular" y="636" left="62" label="Calcular" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

please some help.. :C